# Ordenacion de un List sin que afecte a toda la List

Tags: java-8

Estoy realizando pruebas para realizar con Java8 una ordenación de un List y tengo problemas para poder entender como hacerlo  con java8.Tengo una lista de personas que están ordenadas cuando me vienen por su trabajo pero quiero que por cada trabajo se ordene por edad descendente . Es decir que la lista ya me viene ordenada por cada tipo de trabajo pero quiero ahora utilizar ese list de personas que tengo y por cada tipo de empleo ordenarlo dentro del list que tengo de personas.Guardando siempre el orden del List es decir que el orden viene dado por la base de datos como 1 .Camionero 2.Administrativo 3.contable quiero que dentro de list siga ese orden pero ordenando por edad ya que vienen desordenada la edad(de menor a mayor tendría que ordenar ).He conseguido hacerlo con el sort pero ordeno la lista entera seria ordenar por cada trabajo dentro de la lista.

```
public class Personas {

String edad;
String trabajo;
public String getEdad() {
    return edad;
}
public void setEdad(String edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}
public String getTrabajo() {
    return trabajo;
}
public void setTrabajo(String trabajo) {
    this.trabajo = trabajo;
}
```

}
El list a ordenar seria este;

```
Personas person = new Personas();
    person.setEdad("70");
    person.setTrabajo("camionero");
    personas.add(person);




    Personas person1 = new Personas();
    person1.setEdad("40");
    person1.setTrabajo("camionero");
    personas.add(person1);

    Personas person2 = new Personas();
    person2.setEdad("70");
    person2.setTrabajo("administrativo");
    personas.add(person2);



    Personas person3 = new Personas();
    person3.setEdad("50");
    person3.setTrabajo("administrativo");
    personas.add(person3);




    Personas person4 = new Personas();
    person4.setEdad("70");
    person4.setTrabajo("administrativo");
    personas.add(person4);



    Personas person5 = new Personas();
    person5.setEdad("50");
    person5.setTrabajo("administrativo");
    personas.add(person5);
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.Seguiré buscando  como realizarlo en java8.(En java7 seria realizando un for de la lista indicando que si el get(i).getTrabajo es equal a get(i-1).getTrabajo comprobaria las fechas de los dos y sino se modificaria el anterior para cargar el del siguiente)

Comment: lo suyo es que uses el método collections.sort y compares por trabajo y edad

Comment: He realizado un  personas.sort(( p1, p2)-> {return  Integer.parseInt(p1.getEdad()) > Integer.parseInt(p2.getEdad())? 1 : -1;});  Para que la list se ordene de forma ascendente , despues he realizado personas.sort(Comparator.comparing(Personas:: getTrabajo)); para realizar que me ordene por cada grupo de trabajadores .El problema que esta ordenado pero no se respesta el orden que tenia al principio . Como podria hacer para que dejara el orden de como se ha ingresado en la lista? @JaviMollá  , Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Yo metería las dos comparaciones en una sola. Primero comparas por trabajo y, si son iguales, comparas por edad. En cuanto a que respete el orden original de trabajos, imagino que tendrás que tenerlo en cuenta en el comparador porque si no los ordenará por orden alfabético de trabajo

Comment: Vale voy a intentar dar con ello porque no consigo en el mismo collection que funcionen. Un saludo  y muchas gracias  .@JaviMollá